# Problems uploading to App Store

Tags: app-store, distribution, profile, codesign

Hoping someone can help me here as this is driving me insane.  I used to have no issues uploadeding to app store.... until i updated xcode to v4.

I have tried deleting all certificates, provisioning profiles etc and startng again but that doesnt work.  I have checked that the builds are using the right profiles etc but that still bring up the following message as a yellow fault indicator (so still managed to build succesfully, just doesnt allow me to upload!)

Hopefully someone can help?

```
Validate /Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fwjaruekfnmkdjdwxcykohoidqyg/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app
    cd "/Users/Mac/Documents/Bxxxx/xxxx"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fwjaruekfnmkdjdwxcykohoidqyg/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fwjaruekfnmkdjdwxcykohoidqyg/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app/xxxx
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fwjaruekfnmkdjdwxcykohoidqyg/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app: valid on disk
/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fwjaruekfnmkdjdwxcykohoidqyg/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

Comment: Have you reviewed all the possible causes outlined here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2294/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011374

Comment: I have tried yes... the message i get relates to the third error message warning: Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011).  I have no idea what to do here, never had any issues like this with the old xcode.  The xcode 4.2 version isnt a beta version is it?  If it is apparently it causes these issues too but im sure its not beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Nothing wrong with my coding - this was a certificate issue at Apple's end and that has been cleared up now.

To fix - delete all certificates and keys relating to your development and distribution profile, and mobile provisioning.  Revoke certificates on the provisioning website and reapply for all.

This fixed mine, now no issues and app submitted fine!!